# How to unit test flask w/ flask-socket extension

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write a unit test for a Flask route that's decorated with `@Sockets.route`. With normal Flask routes, I can set up a test client as a context manager and use that to send requests, but I'm not sure what the analogue is for web sockets.

This is the code I'm trying to write a unit test for:

```
from flask_sockets import Sockets

sockets = Sockets(app)

@sockets.route('/test')
def echo_socket(ws):
    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        ws.send('success')
```

The documentation for Flask-Sockets says I should use the gunicorn worker, but I'm not really clear how to get access to one of those from a unit test (just using the unittest module). I have something like:

```
def test_echo_socket:
    # this is all incorrect
    with my_app.app.test_client() as context:    
        context.get('/test')
        self.assertEqual(context.response_code, '101')
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to get a websocket context for unit testing? Thanks.